# Как правильно оформить запрос Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос, он вытаскивает из таблички данные по двум условиям, по дате  и по коду абонента:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM selling WHERE DATE_FORMAT(TransactionDatetime, '%Y-%m') = '2012-$mons' AND CardGroupMemberKey='$enum'"; (РАБОТАЕТ)
```

Как правильно добавить третье условие? Например, я хочу выбирать по дате, по коду, и по адресу.

Пробовал так:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM selling WHERE DATE_FORMAT(TransactionDatetime, '%Y-%m') = '2012-$mons' AND CardGroupMemberKey='$enum' AND CardType='$org'";(НЕ РАБОТАЕТ)
```

Comment: WHERE поле in (значение, значение) and поле=значение

Comment: @icedev, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: что в ошибках пишет?

Comment: может в значении $org есть кавычки одинарные что портят запрос? вообще значение переменных желательно обернуть чем нить типа mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 1):

вынесено из комментариев.

---

возможно, в значении `$org` есть кавычки, которые и «портят» запрос.

вообще значение переменных желательно обернуть чем-нибудь типа [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string).